# What happens to pre-existing objects as ReactJS re-renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Are the pre-existing objects (DOM and virtual DOM objects) totally destroyed so that they do not occupy any memory?

I am asking in order to understand, while using ReactJS if it is safe or not to change the "state"s and "prop"s frequently.

Comment: Changing state and props is basically what a React app does.

Comment: @jmargolisvt Yes I know. I believe the question was straight forward but let me explain. When you change the state hash, render function is re-run as you know. What if you generated a lot of components within a render function? They are re-generated, that is OK. What about the previously generated ones? Do they occupy any memory or they are just cleared as the re-render is passed? That is the question.

Comment: It's more complicated than that.  I think this will answer your question: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html

Comment: No it is not more complicated. That link hints the answer. The questions scope is "what does React (and also the browser libraries) do to 'destroy' the objects, do they free the memory immediately for example? Is is safe to use lots of components?" 

I believe the question is still open even though not "liked"...

Comment: It's def. safe to use lots of components.  React doesn't touch the DOM outside of its domain, so the usual rules apply there.

Comment: Thank you, that is a proper answer now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is an extremely powerful tool for manipulating the DOM. It uses different lifecycles for its components so it doesn't touch the components unless absolutely required. You don't need to worry about its memory management, you can totally change states and pass props the way you need to in your app without worrying about the performance.

States are what help manage a component's lifecycle, change on state triggers a re-render, that's pretty much where most of the re-rendering happens. So it is "**Safe**" to use the states in React, it's is a "*feature*" you need to use to tell react to manage your components. All in all, you don't need to worry about performance, React does that for you, unless you're creating a full fledged game/app that re-renders thousands of components every millisecond. That's when I'd worry about performance.